# Align 3 dynamic views in one row

Tags: react-native

i want to align 3 Views in a row:
|Icon| |Title| |Buttons|
The Title can be more than one line. The buttons are 0-3 Buttons, so their width is unknown to me.

Now the problem is, if I got more than one line in the title the buttons are cut off. How can i solve this and make sure the buttons are always on the screen and the title just has the space that is left?

[On this screenshot 2 listitems are visible. Both should have 3 buttons on the right, but with the long title in the second row, the buttons are cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxTOO.png)

```
        render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.view} underlayColor={'#eee'} onPress={this.props.navigateToDetails}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                    <View style={styles.header}>
                        <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
                           <MaterialIcons style={styles.icon} name={"worker"}/>
                            <MentionsText style={styles.title}
                            >
                                {this.props.siteVisitNote.title}
                            </MentionsText>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.buttons}>
                            <FontAwesomeIcons style={styles.icon} name="tag"/>
                            {Utils.objectExists(this.props.siteVisitNote.attachments) || true ?
                                <FontAwesomeIcons style={styles.icon} name="paperclip"/> : null}
                            {Utils.objectExists(this.props.siteVisitNote.images) || true ?
                                <FontAwesomeIcons style={styles.icon} name="picture-o"/> : null}
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <MentionsText style={styles.text}
                    >{this.getText()}</MentionsText>
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: "space-between",
    },
    headerTitle: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    view: {
        flex: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        borderBottomColor: '#efeff4',
        padding: 8,
        minHeight: 40,
    },
    buttons: {
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: 20,
        paddingRight: 5,
        color: "#333333",
        padding: 8
    },
    title: {
        color: "#333333",
        fontSize: 14,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        padding: 8,
    },
    text: {
        color: "#333333",
        fontSize: 14,
        padding: 8
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide code of your component. Otherwise nobody can help you.

Comment: added code. Is it understandable or do you need more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to `headerTitle`, and `title`.

If that doesn't work see my working example of this layout here which you can compare.

https://gist.github.com/WilliamIPark/2ad3ecf47c5c1e559086e4b10d0cf018

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{ backgroundColor: '#edf2f9'}}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
      >
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.iconTitle}>
              <View style={styles.icon} />
              <Text>Hello world</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonWrap}>
              <View style={styles.button} />
              <View style={styles.button} />
              <View style={styles.button} />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>
            Some other content...
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <View style={styles.iconTitle}>
              <View style={styles.icon} />
              <Text style={styles.title}>
                Hello world this is some really long title right here, that
                goes on and on and on. And then some!
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.buttonWrap}>
              <View style={styles.button} />
              <View style={styles.button} />
              <View style={styles.button} />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View>
            <Text>
              Some other content...
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#edf2f9',
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 200,
    width: 320,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowOffset: {x: 10, y: 10},
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  header: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomColor: 'lightgrey',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  iconTitle:{
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  icon: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    marginRight: 5,
  },
  title: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  buttonWrap: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    marginLeft: 5,
  }
});
```